# How do i create and manage my database for online website?

Tags: database, heroku

I imported my Symfony project on heroku to see how it will be on production. But i got this error:

> 2022-03-18T13:30:30.230251+00:00 app[web.1]: [18-Mar-2022 13:30:30 UTC] [critical] Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: "An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" at /app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/API/MySQL/ExceptionConverter.php line 103
> 2022-03-18T13:30:30.230298+00:00 app[web.1]

So it means that they can not connect to my database, it seems normal since the DATABASE_URL in the .env file is for the localhost(phpmyadmin, root, pwd ="", etc). I have seen that we can add add-ons and i tried to add one for database(ClearDB) but they asked for Credit card(but my one is not available now). I am now looking for a database manager so that i can create my database, get the database's parameters(username, password, etc.) and add it to the heroku app so that i can do my migrations and launch the wesbite.
Is this possible, with which software ?

Comment: Please. I am open to all ideas.

Comment: The best option is what you have already tried: provision an add-on. But as you have seen, this [requires account verification via credit card](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification#when-is-verification-required). If you switch from MySQL to PostgreSQL you could use the Heroku Postgres free tier, which does _not_ require a verified account. If you do that, I strongly suggest changing to PostgreSQL for local development, too.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will now learn PostgreSQL.